# PHP CURL always returns null

Tags: php, curl

I want to get any page of this web site: http://alhayat.com using curl.

This my code so far:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_STRICT);
function getData($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1, 
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
        CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => true,
        CURLOPT_FILETIME => true,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 55,
        CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => 0,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 45,
        CURL_HTTP_VERSION => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
        CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => true,
    ));

    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    if(curl_errno($ch))
    {
        echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    $data = json_decode($data, true);

    return $data;
}
$url = 'http://alhayat.com';
var_dump(getData($url));
```

but the return value is always null.

I tried to find a solution, but nothing worked.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's in `$data` that is returned by this `$data = curl_exec($ch);` line? Why do you think it's json there?

Comment: what returns `var_dump($data)` ?

Comment: Before the Jason_decode function check the response by echo $data; to debug the response.

Comment: `json_decode()`? what are you expecting anyway?

Comment: Just by visiting the webpage (http://alhayat.com), there doesn't seem to be any JSON available to get.

Comment: oh
I veeeeeeeeeeery sorry i Did not attention
sorry again

Comment: i deleted this line ($data = json_decode($data, true);) and the script work in localhost, but in my server only this web site (alhayat.com) return (504 Gateway Time-out) and another web site work.

whay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete the line

```
$data = json_decode($data, true);
```

that will return the site as return value

Comment: i deleted this line ($data = json_decode($data, true);) and the script work in localhost, but in my server only this web site (alhayat.com) return (504 Gateway Time-out) and another web site work. whay?

Comment: maybe you have a slow connection on your server and need a longer CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT? Try set `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 600`

Comment: i get this message:
error: couldn't connect to hostbool(false).

Any ideas?