# Same API returns different results

Tags: php, curl

I need some advice. I need to get data from API to display it on my application. The API is working both through Postman or through the browser, but when I upload the same code to the server, my API response returns NULL.

Here is the response I am getting with POSTMAN:

[image: Screenshot1]

And here is the code I am using:

```
$ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.instagram.com/myexcellentuser/?__a=1');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
  $file_data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
  curl_close($ch);
  var_dump($file_data);
```

And here is what this same code returns on the app hosted on a server:

[image: Screenshot2]

I would be extremely grateful for the advice!

Thanks!

Comment: Are there any errors, cURL errors or PHP errors? What have you tried to do to debug this so far?

Comment: `echo curl_exec($ch);` to see what you get, maybe it's not JSON.

Comment: I used curl_error to see if there are any errors, but it returned nothing.

Comment: comment out this line `// $file_data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));` and replace with: `$file_data = curl_exec($ch);` [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25695993/php-curl-always-returns-null)

Comment: @Newby then if cURL is ok you need to reivew the next step - the JSON bit.

Comment: @Martin, tried your way, commented out my initla $file_data and replaced with curl_exec. Tried to var_dump new $file_data, but got:  ("curl_exec(): supplied resource is not a valid cURL handle resource").

Comment: Please write this line and see status code, maybe it has error:
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

Comment: @RaminRezazadeh returns 0

Comment: This error says the URL not reachable, please check the URL is accessible or not. I can not access to this URL.

Comment: This code works on local server.

Comment: @RaminRezazadeh for security reasons, I changed my users account name to myexcellentuser

Comment: @Newby  When you did the "tried your way, commented out my initla ... " test, did you put the new `curl_exec()` call _after_ your `curl_close()` bychance?

Comment: @PatrickQ ```$ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.instagram.com/holywoodeyewear/?__a=1');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_close($ch);
        $file_data = curl_exec($ch);
        
        print_r($file_data);```

Comment: This is exactly what I was talking about: `curl_close($ch); $file_data = curl_exec($ch);`  You are closing the curl handle before executing it.  So, obviously, that's not going to work.

Comment: It look like the SSL is missing for CURL Options. Check the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/44372276/310160

Comment: @PatrickQ, You were right, but, the result is still the same - NULL

Comment: @balakrishnan, tried to add ```curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);```.  But the result is the same. This is some kind of mistery

Comment: Instagram blocks requests to non-API endpoints like this from most major server providers, as scraping is against their terms of service.

Comment: @ceejayoz, But why it allows the same requests from my local server? So in other words, there is no way around this?

Comment: @Newby It allows the same requests from your local because you're not in a blocked big server provider's IP range when you're at home. There's likely no way around this - Instagram takes a lot of steps to prevent scraping. (You'll probably find your local hits a captcha after a while, too.)

Comment: @ceejayoz is right. Your server is likely blocked by Instagram since that API is not available for public consumption. I tried your code using my username and it worked in my local and server.

Comment: @Newby the way around it is to either use the new API, or to route your requests through proxies. Do you have another server to try on?

Comment: @David, I will try to use a proxy. Thank you! Currently, I just saved the JSON as a text file and fetching it on the server.